# Проблема передачи состояния Модели из контроллера в представление

Tags: c#, веб-программирование, asp.net-mvc, веб-сервер

Доброго времени суток, коллеги. Проект построен на .NET MVC5. Суть вот в чём, есть форма, в которой реализованы 3 кнопки: одна запустить, вторая остановить, третья обновить. При запуске необходимо сделать так, чтобы кнопка стала заблокированной, а кнопка остановить стала активной и при возврате сообщения обратно в Label не сбрасывалась строка с именем устройства.

[image: URL формы до отправки на сервер]

Данный скрипт отправляет данные на контроллер для обработки:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function sendMessage(id, state) {
    switch (state) {
       case 'on':
            var isAlert = confirm("Вы уверенны, что хотите включить нагрузку?");
            if (isAlert) {
                var name = "@Model.object_name";

                var myform = document.getElementById('post_form');
                myform.onsubmit = function () {
                    document.getElementById('pusk_id').value = id;
                    document.getElementById('pusk_state').value = 1;
                    document.getElementById('object_name').value = name;
                    var myButton_on = document.getElementById('puskatel1_on');
                    myButton_on.disabled = true;
                    document.getElementById('puskatel1_on').value = 1;
                    var myButton_off = document.getElementById('puskatel1_off');
                    myButton_off.disabled = false;
                    document.getElementById('puskatel1_off').value = 0;
                    myform.submit();
                };
            }

            break;
        case 'off':
            var isAlert = confirm("Вы уверены, что хотите отключить накрузку?");
            if (isAlert) {

                var myform = document.getElementById('post_form');
                myform.onsubmit = function () {
                    document.getElementById('pusk_id').value = id;
                    document.getElementById('pusk_state').value = 0;
                    document.getElementById('object_name').value = "@Model.object_name";
                    var myButton_off = document.getElementById('puskatel1_off');
                    myButton_off.disabled = true;
                    document.getElementById('puskatel1_off').value = 1;
                    var myButton_on = document.getElementById('puskatel1_on');
                    myButton_on.disabled = false;
                    document.getElementById('puskatel1_on').value = 0;
                    myform.submit();
                };
            }

            break;
        case 'netral':
            var myform = document.getElementById('post_form');
            myform.onsubmit = function () {
                document.getElementById('pusk_id').value = id;
                document.getElementById('object_name').value = "@Model.object_name";
                myform.submit();
            };

            break;
    }
}

function stateButtonFotLoad() {   // вызывается при старте, чтобы обновить состояние кнопок в Модели и сделать кнопки одна заблокирована другая нет.
    sendMessage(-1, 'netral');
    document.getElementById("puskatel1_off").disabled = @Model.puskatel1_form_off;
    document.getElementById("puskatel1_on").disabled = @Model.puskatel1_form_on;
}
window.onload = stateButtonFotLoad;
```

Данная форма отправляет скрытые поля POST-методом:

```
  <div style="border: 1px solid #d6e9c6; float:left; width: 400px; margin-bottom:20px;">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title">Панель управления нагрузкой для @Model.object_name</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <form name="post_form" id="post_form" method="post" action="Partial" onsubmit="DoSubmit();">
                   @Html.Hidden("pusk_id", "0")
                  @Html.Hidden("pusk_state", "")
                  @Html.Hidden("object_name", "")
                  @Html.Hidden("puskatel1_form_off", "true")
                  @Html.Hidden("puskatel1_form_on", "false")

            <label style="margin-right: 15px; margin-bottom:15px;">Пускатель 1:</label>
            <button id="puskatel1_off" name="puskatel1_off" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="sendMessage(1, 'off')">Выключить</button>
            <button id="puskatel1_on" name="puskatel1_on" class="btn btn-success" onclick="sendMessage(1, 'on')">Включить</button><br>

            <label>Сообщение: <span>@Model.outputmessage</span></label><br>
            <label name="lblInfo"></label>
             <br>

            <button name="refresh" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="sendMessage(-1,'netral')">Обновить</button>
        </form>
```

На контроллере выполняются разные действия над этими данными и возвращается обратно модель.

```
return View(post_form); // обычно так
```

Идея заключается в том, чтобы когда мы заходим для другого устройства сразу вызывался метод обновления для него и не сбрасывалось устройство в строке. 
В функции обновить записываются в Модель состояния для кнопок если true блокируем, false не блокируем.

**Вопрос:** Как сохранять состояния для представления в передаваемых объектах?

Обработчики, данных с формы:

```
[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Partial(string name)
    {
        send_device_message send = new send_device_message();
        send.object_name = name;

        return View(send);
    } 

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Partial(send_device_message post_form)
    {          
        if (post_form.pusk_id == 0)
        {
            post_form.outputmessage = "Действие отменено.";
            return View(post_form);
        }
        else if (post_form.pusk_id == -1)
        {
            string pusk1_cloud = post_form.factStartDevice;
            string pusk1_dev = post_form.realyStartDevice;

            RefreshStatusDevice(post_form);

            return View(post_form);
        }
        else
        {
            int state = Convert.ToInt32(post_form.pusk_state);
            string object_name = post_form.object_name;

            UpdatePuskToCloud(state, object_name);

            if (state == 0)
            {
                post_form.outputmessage = "Пускатель " + post_form.pusk_id + ", устройства " + post_form.object_name + " выключен.";
            }
            if (state == 1)
            {
                post_form.outputmessage = "Пускатель " + post_form.pusk_id + ", устройства " + post_form.object_name + " включен.";
            }
            if (state < 100)
            {
                send_message = "{\"Puskatel" + post_form.pusk_id + "\":" + state + "}";
                send_object_name = post_form.object_name;

                System.Threading.ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(a => SendCloudToDeviceMessage());
            }

            return View(post_form);

        }
    }
```

Comment: `myform.onsubmit = function () { ... myform.submit(); }` - wtf?

Comment: @Igor это отправка формы. При клике по кнопке происходит запуск функции _sendMessage()_, в которой происходит вылет сообщения и если ответ утвердительный начинают заполняться _hidden_ поля. Потом осуществляется отправка формы.

Comment: Я думаю, что понимаю, что Вы *хотели* сделать. В действительности, "если ответ утвердительный" - то форме назначется обработчик `onsubmit` (кстати, что будет с `onsubmit="DoSubmit();"`?) и все. Потом когда-то, этот обработчик вызывается (форма в это время находится в процессе submit-а), и из него опять инициируется отправка формы `myform.submit();`.

Comment: @Igor пардон с 'onsubmit="DoSubmit();" ' ничего не произойдёт, т.к. было по другому сделано и после изменений просто не убрал.

Comment: @Igor Хочу сделать так, чтобы после действий на контроллере страница загружалась со значениями, которые определились во время обработки и блокировали кнопки. В скрипте есть момент блокировки кнопок, но блокировка слетает после перегрузки страницы.

Comment: Выделяйте из Вашего кода более простые и конкретные задачи. Упрощайте все до предела. Например: параметр `post_form` в `[HttpPost] public ActionResult Partial` содержит значения установленные в браузере?

Comment: Содержит значения, которые передаются из формы в представлении.